# Frequency of tenses

Tags: tense, writing, frequency

Out of pure curiosity, I wonder how frequently each of the 12 tenses is used in the written English language. I only found a passing remark, that [Present Simple, Past Simple, and Present Perfect account for 98% of tensed verbs in published academic texts](http://www.cambridge.org/grammarandbeyond/newsletter/2014/04/how-many-tenses-do-students-really-need-to-learn).

To be precise, I am looking for some research on frequency of the tenses over a general corpus of English written texts.

Comment: Since the past perfect refers to a past event relative to another past event which is closer to the present, it is unlikely to be used outside of narrative contexts (which might include history, but in academic history texts, the present is often used by convention, instead of the past tenses.) So if you want this answer with regard to the spoken language, you'd have to look at something other than academic texts-- if you wanted to avoid skewed results.  Not my downvote, BTW.

Comment: Beautifully interesting; but sadly, I'm not sure if something like this could objectively be done in a Q/A. For one thing, people still can't agree on what to call tense. Most of them don't, anyway. Congratulations for being the third post I upvote and vote to close on ELL.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about learning the English language within the scope defined in the help center.  English.SE might be a better fit.

Comment: This is emphatically **on-topic**: since the 1960s there have been many corpus studies which examined the relative frequency of various verbforms and verb constructions in order to determine which should be taught and where learners should direct their attention.

Comment: @Stoney the problem is: How are you planning for a comprehensive and good answer to this question?

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. I have given an answer which at least provides a start; I hope others will come along and add established results which augment or replace it. There will of course never be a 'final' answer; but all anybody can ask for on any SE site is a 'state-of-the-art' answer.

Comment: @StoneyB I haven't voted to close, because I do think this is on-topic, but I wonder if it would get a better response if it were migrated to EL&U.

Comment: @ColleenV Hmm ... There's a lot of folks on ELU who do quick queries on COCA and BNC; but this is a more complex question that I think requires familiarity with the published literature, and I haven't noticed a lot of interest in that over there.

Comment: I see what you did there @Stoney, the problem is the "too broad" reason fits this occasion well. Nonetheless, I'd rather not be the pebble in the way; sometimes the community likes to bend rules it enforces and I'm fine with that; as long as we don't play like this on every question, which I know we won't, since this wasn't a typical inquiry. Last comment; retracted close vote.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm not active on ELU so I wasn't sure. It looked good on paper ;)

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Actually it's not that broad -- an entirely responsive answer could be expressed in a single table the size of the one in my answer. The trick is finding the table!

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ., This question started with somebody quoting their English teacher saying "The present perfect is the most frequently used tense".  I preferred posting this question on ELL, because I was concerned that on ELU there will be too much "what is simple"/"what is tense" tension :) If you are ESL student or especially teaching English to ESL learners, a tense is just a tense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Graeme Kennedy, ‘Preferred ways of putting things with implications for language teaching’, in Jan Svartvik, ed., *Directions in Corpus Linguistics: Proceedings of Nobel Symposium 82* (*Trends in Linguistics. Studies and Monographs ; 65*), 1991, gives this table of results from corpus studies carried out in the 1960s.

[image: FiniteFormFrequencies]

This is just a start to an answer. Kennedy's paper identifies many additional studies which, alas, I do not have access to.

Comment: Exactly the table I was looking for. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @HingeSight Be careful, though. These don't discriminate consistently between active and passive and they don't appear to include modal constructions or constructions with future reference. And the quality of the corpora is not evident--both corpora and corpus studies have gotten a *lot* more sophisticated in the last fifty years.